# echo $? return 1 after use ssh -T parameter connected remote host

Tags: shell, ssh

I'm use `ssh -T foo@bar` to login a remote host.But `echo $?` command response `1` after login success.
Besides, `echo $?` return `0` if I'm use `ssh -t foo@bar`.

Code `1` means `Catchall for general errors`.

1. What's the means in that stage?
2. How to fix it?
   Thanks

**UPDATE #1**
Some clarify:
1. Q: Are you running `echo $?` on the server after logging in, or on the client after logging out?
A: `echo $?` runs after login server.It is executed on remote server side.
2. Q: How are you able to log in if you disable TTY allocation with `-T`?
A: It just works and I have test on many machines.
3. Q: Do you not want a shell session maybe?
A: No. I'm just not want use `pseudo-terminal`.It is also a ssh session. I need the "clean" message used at a program.It's not a interactive environment.

Thanks again!

**UPDATE #2**
some environment file.
1. ~/.profile file

```
if [ "$BASH" ]; then
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
  fi
fi

tty -s && mesg n
```

2. ~/.bashrc file  :

   ```
   # ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
   # see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
   # for examples

   # If not running interactively, don't do anything
   [ -z "$PS1" ] && return

   # don't put duplicate lines in the history. See bash(1) for more options
   # ... or force ignoredups and ignorespace
   HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace

   # append to the history file, don't overwrite it
   shopt -s histappend

   # for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
   HISTSIZE=1000
   HISTFILESIZE=2000

    # check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
    # update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
   shopt -s checkwinsize

    # make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
   [ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

     # set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
   if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
       debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
   fi

    # set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
   case "$TERM" in
       xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
   esac

    # uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
    # off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
    # should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
    #force_color_prompt=yes

   if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
       if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
       # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
       # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
       # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
       color_prompt=yes
       else
       color_prompt=
       fi
   fi

   if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
       PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
   else
       PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
   fi
   unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

    # If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
   case "$TERM" in
   xterm*|rxvt*)
       PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
       ;;
   *)
       ;;
   esac

    # enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
   if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
       test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
       alias ls='ls --color=auto'
       #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
       #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

       alias grep='grep --color=auto'
       alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
       alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
   fi

    # some more ls aliases
   alias ll='ls -alF'
   alias la='ls -A'
   alias l='ls -CF'

    # Alias definitions.
    # You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
    # ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
    # See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

   if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
       . ~/.bash_aliases
   fi

    # enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
    # this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
    # sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
    #if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    #    . /etc/bash_completion
    #fi
   ```

Comment: Are you running `echo $?` on the server after logging in, or on the client after logging out? Also, how are you able to log in if you disable TTY allocation with `-T`? Do you not want a shell session maybe?

Comment: hi, I'm just updated on the question.@Kusalananda

Comment: It is likely something in your shell startup files. If you are using `bash`, see if anything in `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` requires a TTY to work correctly (and which fails when there isn't one, giving rise to the non-zero exit status in `$?`).

Comment: Hi, does the config file some error here? I'm don't know how to check it. Sorry for edit broken.... @Kusalananda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use `tty -s` in your `.profile` file, and since the login shell does not have a TTY when logging in with `ssh -T`, this command will fail and set `$?` to 1.

This is expected and the full command

```
tty -s && mesg n
```

relies on this so that `mesg n` (which "disallows messages from other users" through `talk` and `write`, something that I believe is rarely used nowadays) does not execute if there is no TTY.

To "fix" this, simply comment out or remove that line from `.profile`. It will have little impact on anything.

Comment: Hi, it was fixed when I remove the command! Besides, I'm use `man tty`, the `-s` is explained with `print nothing, only return an exit status`.Can you explain what's the means and why it broken?

Comment: Or change it to `if tty -s; then mesg n; fi` or `! tty -s || mesg n`. Or  add a `: make sure the exit status is 0` at the end of the `.profile`

Comment: What's the `exit status`?I'm just login the host why show me a `exit status`?

Comment: @LoranceChen The "exit status" is the integer code that a program returns when it exits. An exit status of zero usually means that the program "succeeded" while a non-zero exit status usually means that "something went wrong", or that a test failed.  `grep` (if you are familiar with that command), for example, returns a non-zero exit status if the pattern that it looked for in a file was not found.

Comment: thanks, It's clear.But I'm also not understand what does `tty -s && mesg n` do. Expecially, "disallows messages from other users"  means.

Comment: @LoranceChen There are a couple of old commands, `talk` and `write`, that other users could use to send messages to you on a multi-user system. The command `mesg n` disallows others to use these commands for contacting you. As I wrote, these commands have fallen out of use in the last few decades and most people don't even know about them.

Comment: Actually, `mesg n` on Linux at least changes the tty open on stderr (in that, it not POSIX), not the controlling terminal, so `[ ! -t 2 ] || mesg n` would be more correct there. POSIXly that would be `if [ -t 0 ] || [ -t 1 ] || [ -t 2 ]; then mesg n; fi`. In practice, it shouldn't  really matter as the file open on stdin, stdout or stderr in `~/.profile` will likely be the controlling terminal if there's one.

Comment: Thanks again, and @StéphaneChazelas.I think I will never use the command. >.<